# Linux: How to put a load on system memory?

Tags: linux, load, cpu

I'm working on a small function, that gives my users a picture of how occupied the CPU is.

I'm using `cat /proc/loadavg`, which returns the well known 3 numbers.

My problem is that the CPU doesn't do anything, right now, while I'm developing.

Is there a good way to generate some load on the CPU, I was thinking something like `makecpudosomething 30`, for a load of 0.3 or similar. Does an application like this exist?

Also, are there any way to eat up RAM in a controlled fashion?

Comment: Start a Java application.

Comment: @Paul - He said "eat up RAM in a controlled fasion". Java would just chew through whatever it wanted...:-P

Comment: Do you want to calculate cpu load or cpu utilization?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I didn't understand very well if you want to generate arbitrary [CPU load or CPU utilization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_%28computing%29#Load_average_is_not_CPU_utilization). Yes, they are different things indeed. I'll try to cover both problems.

First of all: **[load](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load%5F%28computing%29)** is the average number of processes in the *running*, *runnable* or *waiting for CPU* scheduler queues in a given amount of time, "the one that wants your CPU" so to speak.

So, if you want to generate arbitrary **load** (say 0.3) you have to run a process for 30% of the time and then remove it from the run queue for 70% of the time, moving it to the sleeping queue or killing it, for example.

You can try this script to do that:

```
export LOAD=0.3
while true
     do yes > /dev/null &
     sleep $LOAD
     killall yes
     sleep `echo "1 - $LOAD" | bc`
done
```

Note that you have to wait some time (1, 10 and 15 minutes) to get the respective numbers to come up, and it will be influenced by other processes in your system. The more busy your system is the more this numbers will float. The last number (15 minutes interval) tends to be the most accurate.

**[CPU usage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_usage)** is, instead, the amount of time for which CPU was used for processing instructions of a computer program.

So, if you want to generate arbitrary **CPU usage** (say 30%) you have to run a process that is CPU bound 30% of the time and sleeps 70% of it.

I wrote an example to show you that:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define CPUUSAGE 0.3      /* set it to a 0 < float < 1 */
#define PROCESSES 1       /* number of child worker processes */
#define CYCLETIME 50000   /* total cycle interval in microseconds */

#define WORKTIME (CYCLETIME * CPUUSAGE)
#define SLEEPTIME (CYCLETIME - WORKTIME)

/* returns t1-t2 in microseconds */
static inline long timediff(const struct timeval *t1, const struct timeval *t2)
{
  return (t1->tv_sec - t2->tv_sec) * 1000000 + (t1->tv_usec - t2->tv_usec);
}

static inline void gettime (struct timeval *t)
{
  if (gettimeofday(t, NULL) < 0)
  {
    err(1, "failed to acquire time");
  }
}

int hogcpu (void)
{
  struct timeval tWorkStart, tWorkCur, tSleepStart, tSleepStop;
  long usSleep, usWork, usWorkDelay = 0, usSleepDelay = 0;

  do
  {
    usWork = WORKTIME - usWorkDelay;
    gettime (&tWorkStart);
    do
    {
      sqrt (rand ());
      gettime (&tWorkCur);
    }
    while ((usWorkDelay = (timediff (&tWorkCur, &tWorkStart) - usWork)) < 0);

    if (usSleepDelay <= SLEEPTIME)
      usSleep = SLEEPTIME - usSleepDelay;
    else
      usSleep = SLEEPTIME;

    gettime (&tSleepStart);
    usleep (usSleep);
    gettime (&tSleepStop);
    usSleepDelay = timediff (&tSleepStop, &tSleepStart) - usSleep;
  }
  while (1);
  return 0;
}

int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  pid_t pid;
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < PROCESSES; i++)
  {
    switch (pid = fork ())
    {
    case 0:
      _exit (hogcpu ());
    case -1:
      err (1, "fork failed");
      break;
    default:
      warnx ("worker [%d] forked", pid);
    }
  }
  wait(NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

If you want to eat up a fixed amount of RAM you can use the program in the [cgkanchi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/148765/cgkanchi)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1971675/7776212).

Comment: this will use 9%-16% less cpu than the desired value on many, where unfortunately usleep can be off 2ms or longer (e.g.: 25%=3/12 not 30%). max possible cpu% might be 91% vs. 100%. can be closer by adjusting for the overrun (like cpulimit), realtime not needed. still, the OP can just compare ps to his gui. This code is an excellent tool to generate cpu usage, really handy!

Comment: could you link to the cgkanchi's answer?

Answer (score 16):

```
while true;
    do openssl speed;
done
```

also the stress program will let you load the cpu/mem/disk to the levels you want to simulate:

- http://weather.ou.edu/~apw/projects/stress/

> stress is a deliberately simple
>   workload generator for POSIX systems.
>   It imposes a configurable amount of
>   CPU, memory, I/O, and disk stress on
>   the system. It is written in C, and is
>   free software licensed under the
>   GPLv2.

to maintain a particular level of cpu utilization, say 30%, try cpulimit:

- http://cpulimit.sourceforge.net/

it will adapt to the current system environment and adjust for any other activity on the system.

there's also a patch to the kernel for native cpu rate limits here: http://lwn.net/Articles/185489/

Comment: You mistaken what Ingo said. What he meant was "nice +19 tasks gets 1.5% in case of 100% CPU usage", obviously. Why on earth an OS would limit the CPU usage of a process if *the CPU is completely idle* ?

I did a little test on a 2 core CPU: 1 `yes` process with nice 19 and two `yes` processes with nice 0. Indeed, the 1.5% Ingo was talking about. http://gist.github.com/265744

Comment: `stress` link is dead... Couldn't find anything on the big G. Anyone know where it went?

Comment: This is 3 years late, but here's a page - searched google for the description of the project "stress is a deliberately simple... &c."

http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~apw/stress/

Comment: Also stress-ng is an update/fork of stress that allows cpu load to be specified in percentage rather than "number of entire CPUs to max at 100%" http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~cking/stress-ng/

Answer (score 6):

1G memory

```
python -c 'a="a"*1024**3;raw_input()'
```

Comment: I have tried all methods mentioned here, and this is the most useful and easiest way to achieve memory load testing. thanks!

Comment: for Python 3: `python -c 'a="a"*1024**3; input()'`

Answer (score 5):

To eat up a fixed amount of RAM, you could just:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define UNIX 1

//remove the above line if running under Windows

#ifdef UNIX
    #include <unistd.h>
#else
    #include <windows.h>
#endif

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    unsigned long mem;
    if(argc==1)
        mem = 1024*1024*512; //512 mb
    else if(argc==2)
        mem = (unsigned) atol(argv[1]);
    else
    {
        printf("Usage: loadmem <memory in bytes>");
        exit(1);
    }

    char* ptr = malloc(mem);
    while(1)
    {
        memset(ptr, 0, mem);
        #ifdef UNIX
            sleep(120);
        #else
            Sleep(120*1000);
        #endif
    }
}
```

The memset() call seems to be required, because at least on OS X, the actual memory doesn't seem to get used until it is actually initialised.

EDIT: Fixed in response to comment

Comment: OS will swap out all that RAM very soon. You should probably do memset() in a loop so that these pages will stay in RAM.

Comment: This is a very old post but: there is the concept of "lazy allocation" that you are experiencing unless you memset the memory you asked for. As you said, this will simply eat up memory, there are more sophisticated tests to be done with the reserved mem that detect more kinds of errors (that is why you are better of using one of the existing tools).

Answer (score 3):

Very simple actually: install [stress](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stress) tool and do:

```
stress --vm X --vm-bytes YM
```

- replace X with the number of worker you want to spawn and "`malloc()`" your RAM
- replace Y with the amount of memory that each worker has to allocate

Example:

```
stress --vm 2 --vm-bytes 128M
```

Comment: It did not work at all. I did have stress installed

Comment: This answer is from 2014, it is possible that now the stress command has been updated, if I have time I'll re-check the documentation

Comment: It turns out to be I needed to add `--vm-keep` option

Answer (score 3):

you can stress utility, as it is a workload generator tool designed to subject your system to a configurable measure of CPU, memory, I/O and disk stress.

To run 1 vm stressor using 1GB of virtual memory for 60s, enter:

stress --vm 1 --vm-bytes 1G --vm-keep -t 60s

Answer (score 2):

You can try http://code.google.com/p/stressapptest/

Answer (score 2):

Use "memtester" to do your memory regression tests in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I took this program and modify the line: mem = 1024*1024*512; //512 mb
to say this: mem = 1*1024*1024*1024; //1 GB
and compile it.

$ gcc iss_mem.c -o iss_mem

And write a bash wrapper around the compiled version of the C program above. It helps me generate a lot of memory load in my server.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Author: Mamadou Lamine Diatta
#         Senior Principal Consultant / Infrastructure Architect
# Email:  diatta at post dot harvard dot edu
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# *************************************************************************************

memsize_kb=`grep -i MemTotal /proc/meminfo | awk '{print $2}'`
MemTotal=$(($memsize_kb*1024))
for i in `seq 1 50`
do

        echo "`date +"%F:%H:%M:%S"` ----------------- Running [ $i ] iteration(s)"
        MemToAlloc=$((1*1024*1204*1204))
            # 1Gb of memory per iss_mem call
        TRESHOLD=$(($MemTotal/$MemToAlloc))
             # We are not supposed to make the system
             # run out of memory
        rand=1000
            # High enough to force a new one
        while (( $rand > $TRESHOLD ))
        do
                rand=$(($RANDOM/1000))
        done
        if [ $rand -eq 0 ]
        then
                rand=1
        fi

        echo `date +"%F:%H:%M:%S"` Running $rand iss_mem in parallel ...
        for j in `seq 1 $rand`
        do
             ${ISSHOME}/bin/iss_mem > /dev/null &
                # NOTE: gcc iss_mem.c -o iss_mem
        done

        sleep 180
        jobs -p
        kill `jobs -p`

        sleep 30


done
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# *************************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [prime95](http://www.mersenne.org/freesoft/)?

I'm not sure if you can limit it to a percentage like that tho...

Answer (score 0):

```
mark@localhost$ time pi 1048576 | egrep '.*total$'
```

Is a simple benchmarking command that will give your cpu a rousting, post your times :D

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I have found to load the RAM (and SWAP) is by using Perl:

```
my $allocation = "A" x (1024 * 1024 * $ARGV[0]);
print "\nAllocated " . length($allocation) . "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this application will be useful:

https://www.devin.com/lookbusy/

Steps to install and usage is found in github project which uses lookbusy.

https://github.com/beloglazov/cpu-load-generator

Snippet from Github page:

To generate a sequence of 20%, 90%, and 50% CPU utilization for 20 seconds each on 2 cores using the test.data file,

```
python cpu-load-generator.py -n 2 20 test.data
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought this post had a creative answer for this. [Credit to solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99334/how-to-fill-90-of-the-free-memory/254976#254976)

Example, this should "stress" 100 MB for 2 minutes

```
cat <(yes | tr \\n x | head -c $((1024*1024*100))) <(sleep 120) | grep n
```