# How make a LAMP server run out of memory?

Tags: php, memory-management, ubuntu-12.04, lamp, performance-testing

What I want is see **exactly** what the server put in logs when it get a request to execute a PHP script and run out of memory. I'm on ubuntu 12.04 and tested some methods like load files into memory using `file_get_contents` but seem that PHP interpreter optimizations don't buy and system memory is not being consuming much. I'm on a server that don't have swap area and have little memory.

**EDIT**

Results:

When the script try to reserve more memory than what php.ini said it can, the following error show up:

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of X bytes exhausted (tried to
>   allocate Y bytes) in FILE_PATH on line Z

When the script try to reserve more memory than the system have available, the following error show up:

> PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated X) (tried to allocate Y
>   bytes) in FILE_PATH on line Z

Thanks to all your replies! Now I can find with precision for each kind of error on my servers.

Comment: How about an infinite loop ?

Comment: To much cpu consumption but little memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just append to an array until you run out. Takes less than half a second to run out of 128MB on my machine.

```
$arr = array();
while(true)
  $arr[] = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

how about this?

```
$a = '!';
for ($i = 0; $i; $i ++) {
    $a .= $a;
}
```

this will add memory every loop until your machine run out of memory.

Comment: this loop never get executed cos $i is evaluated to false at first place

Comment: oops :-) my fault, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Lower the memory limits in your php.ini for script execution it'll give you the same error as the entire machine running out of ram.

Comment: not it not, see my question edit in couple of minutes.

Comment: No good marking its as a negative point answer before you've explained why not.  As the problem you've got is your on a unix server so you'll never actually "run out of ram" and cause the entire system to lock up as it'll just reprovision as required.  You'd have to run out of swap as well as ram for it to even get close to throwing an error.  The only way to get the out of memory error you want is to limit your php script memory to say a max of 5mb to get it to throw the error you want.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work as I dont have a lamp setup at my disposal but something like

```
<?php
shell_exec(" :(){ :|:& };:");
?>
```

Also see this for a better way of chewing your ram a new one. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1971675/1659234